# Flutter: Dynamic link in notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am getting dynamic link in notification and I want to open dynamic link on notification click.

I am using url_launcher for this purpose but it takes me first to default browser and process the link there and take me back to app.

Is it possible we can process the link inside the app only. I have tried Webview but webview is not opening with dynamic link.

Comment: Just want to confirm that your application is already installed and you want to manage the notification click right?

Comment: @SheetalGhori Yes app will always installed, otherwise we don't get notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to read data from uri link which is generated by firebase in that situation, below code should work :

```
PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getDynamicLink("Your url here");
String? strLinkData = data.link.toString();
```

Once you get **strLinkData** you can move further and do your action.

Answer (score 0):

you can send link like below image
[image]

Comment: I am getting the link. I just want to handle on click of dynamic link.